# Caravan Automatic Transmission gear selector

Tags: automatic-transmission, dodge, caravan

2001 Caravan. Very hard to change from park to any other gear.  Selector very loose when pulling down to shift but very hard to get it to stop at a specific gear. Then it is almost impossible to put back into park without a hard jamming.  Is there a bracket maybe that is supposed to hold the selector in place as it seems very loose once it is moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check on the side of the transaxle where the cable attaches to the transmission. It sounds like the bracket, lever, or ball may be loose.